# Input controls working simultaneously.how to update the values in one while another changes without making a loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm

I have two input controls working simultaneously, **A** and **B**. If **A**'s value changed, **B** should be moved to that value.
If **B** changed **A** should be shifted to this value.
How do I setup the algorithm?

I tried creating one but it behaves improperly since the change will make a loop. Any help is appreciated.

```
if(A Changed)
change B's value to value of A
if( B Changed)
change A's value to value of B
```

EDIT:
Real scenario..A: Carousel 
B:slider

```
- (void)carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
        [self.slider setValue:self.carousel.currentItemIndex];
}
-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id) sender{    
    [self.carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:self.slider.value animated:YES];
}
```

PROBLEM: sliderChanged: methods is connected to action `valuechanged`

So whenever carousel gets moved set the slider accordingly to the value that in carousel.When carousel changed change the value of slider

REQUIREMENT: Use a slider to scroll the carousel so that for larger values the swipe can be reduced by moving the slider

Comment: You need to provide more specific code. Without knowing what A and B are and how you are really changing their values, there is no way to give a good answer.

Comment: Calling the `UISlider setValue:` should not trigger a change event. Are you finding otherwise? The change event should only be called if the user changes the slider value through the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

So right now, the way you have it, the system has two states it responds to, A-change and B-change. Of course A-change causes B-change and vice versa, so you have an infinite loop whenever anything changes.

But how can it be any other way? Well, one thing you can consider is the changes themselves, and who is doing the changes. In one case, the user inputs data and that's a change. Obviously, you know how you want to handle that case. But then another change occurs, the program itself actually changes something in response to a user change. And THAT case, you probably want to handle a different way.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to have a single model value behind the scenes that both A and B update, then also have A and B *observe* that model value and make changes accordingly. You can do the former by just updating your existing code to change the value, and the latter by using [key-value observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).